# Can I explicitly specify ENGINE=InnoDB in Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, database, mysql, innodb

I converted all my tables to InnoDB, but the MySQL server (which I can't access, as I'm on shared hosting) has MyISAM as the default, so every new table that Wordpress creates (e.g. when I add a new site on my multisite) uses the MyISAM engine and I have to alter it manually. Can I somehow set Wordpress up to enforce the InnoDB engine when creating new tables?

I know that by default Wordpress doesn't specify anything and lets the table use the default engine, but I'm wondering if there is some plugin where I could add the

```
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

clause to all the `CREATE TABLE` queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code creating new tables uses `dbDelta()` (it should), you can filter the query (see `wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php`):

```
add_filter( 'dbdelta_create_queries', function( Array $queries )
{
    foreach ( $queries as $table => $query )
    {
        if ( FALSE !== stripos( $query, 'CREATE TABLE' ) )
        {
            // change the query here
        }
    }

    return $queries;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Found the code in question. Maybe it could be made even simpler by adding a filter for `'dbdelta_create_queries'`, as I see it's already defined in the code to match `"|CREATE TABLE ([^ ]*)|"`.

Comment: @kermit666 Indeed, that’s better. :) Made an update to my answer.